# Using python I need to remove commas from my excel file and then convert it to csv

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have the python code to convert an excel file to csv, however portions of the data in the excel file have commas which affects the conversion.

What would be the best way, staying within python, to remove the commas then convert?

Comment: If you remove the commas, whatever they were separating within the "portions of data" will get bunched together. Is that OK? If it is, @aydin's answer might be a good the way to go, because the Python `csv` module can handle just about any unique single character delimiter via it's `delimiter` keyword argument (see the example in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-contents) where a space character is being specified).

Comment: Why not just take the Excel file and `SaveAs` CSV. This *should* produce a properly formatted CSV file, and use doublequote as the text qualifier, so those *commas within strings* would not be treated as delimiters.

Comment: Prefer for this to be fully automated, eliminating any need to manually open an excel file. Martineau, I want the "portions of data" to be bunched together. All commas are found in the same data cell which is free text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can convert from excel to csv using a different delimiter, e.g. `;` instead of comma, you can remove the commas from the converted file, then convert the csv delimiter (`;`) back to comma.

Comment: True, however there is a possibility that there might be ";"'s also. One of the data cells is free text. I will experiment to find a unique delimiter. Thanks.